# Bootstrap 3 Background Image multiple Sections

Tags: html, css, image, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Hi I need help with my background image. I want to use one image for multiple sections. If I scroll the image should remain. When I link the image in the HTML tag it works. but then it is not responsive. I've also tried it in the body tag.

I'am using the twitter bootstrap frameweork.

Can anyone help, thanks in advance !

**CSS**

```css
background: url(../img/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
```

**HTML**

```html
<!-- Intro Section -->
<section id="intro" class="intro-section">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>

<!-- About Section -->
<section id="about" class="about-section">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <h1>About Section</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think something is missing from your code. See the following example:

```
    body {
        background: url('/Images/Hero.png') ghostwhite no-repeat center center fixed;
        -webkit-background-size: cover;
        -moz-background-size: cover;
        -o-background-size: cover;
        -ms-background-size: cover;
        background-size: cover;
    }
```

Also make sure that the style is attached to the top most wrapper or div.

On a side note, sometimes specifying the 'container' class will lead to unexpected css issues. try removing it.

Comment: thx for the fast answer. I tried this before and it works. But only for the desktop version not on mobile. I've checked iPad and iPhone and there is the image not responsive.

Answer (score 0):

To to use one image for multiple sections use background-size: cover CSS property. Use the section class selectors separated by a comma.

```
.intro-section, .about-section {
             background: url(images/slide1.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
            -webkit-background-size: cover;
            -moz-background-size: cover;
            background-size: cover;
            -o-background-size: cover;

          }
```

Comment: ty Denise. Ok i did it. it works but the same result as in the answer above.